# jQuery to show/hide divs in a JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a slight problem with my jQuery and I can't quite figure out where my problems lies, so if anyone could give me a hand with it is greatly appreciated.

I am using a jQuery function that when my `#add` div gets clicked, a JavaBean is called which adds the current page to the session *user* and when the `#remove` div gets clicked, a similar process is carried out that removes the current page from the user.

My problems starts when I try to check with the collection whether the current page is already associated with the user and if so display the `#remove` div and otherwise display the `#add` div.

Below is my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#viewshow-text").load(function(){
            if(${userShowDetails}) { <%-- this var can either be true or false depending on whether the page is associated with the user or not --%>
                $('#removeshow').show(),
                $('#addshow').hide();
            } else {
                $('#addshow').show(),
                $('#removeshow').hide();
            }
        });
        $("#add").click(function() {
            $.post("addshow", {
                item : "${param.show}"
            }, function(data, status) {

            }, function() {
                <%-- hide a div and display the other --%>
                $this.find('#addshow').hide(),
                $this.find('#removeshow').show();
            });

        });
        $("#remove").click(function() {
            $.post("removeshow", {
                item : "${param.show}"
            }, function(data, status) {

            }, function() {
                $this.find('#removeshow').hide(),
                $this.find('#addshow').show();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My div elements in question are as follows:

```
<div class="viewshow-text">
  <c:if test="${!empty USER}"> <%-- only display if a user is logged in --%>
    <div id="addshow" class="viewshow-button viewshowAdd-button">
      <a id="add" href="#">Add to calendar</a>
    </div>
    <div id="removeshow" class="viewshow-button viewshowRemove-button">
      <a id="remove" href="#">Remove from calendar</a>
    </div>
  </c:if>
</div>
```

I have no issues with my JavaBean properties as I double checked and they are displaying the contents expected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(if(false) {
            $('#removeshow').show(),
            $('#addshow').hide();
        } else {
            $('#addshow').show(),
            $('#removeshow').hide();
        });
```

When the page is not in the user list.

Comment: Could you show the code with which you initialize userShowDetails?

Comment: <c:set var="userShowDetails" value="${userShowManager.contains(USER, param.show)}" />
I have double checked it and I know for sure it display either true or false correctly!

Answer (score 2):

Here try this,

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
      if(${userShowDetails}) {
        $('#removeshow').show(),
        $('#addshow').hide();
       } else {
        $('#addshow').show(),
        $('#removeshow').hide();

      };
      $("#add").click(function() {
       $.post("addshow", {
        item : "${param.show}"
       }).done(function(data) {
        $('#addshow').hide(),
        $('#removeshow').show();
       });
      });
      $("#remove").click(function() {
       $.post("removeshow", {
        item : "${param.show}"
       }).done(function(data) {
        $('#removeshow').hide(),
        $('#addshow').show();
       });
      });
     });
    </script>
```